# Regularized sum

Tags: regularization

How could I prove that as $ \epsilon \to 0 $ the regularized series goes as

$$ \sum _{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\exp(-n\epsilon)}{n}=-\log(1-e^{-\epsilon}) $$

and how could I prove that the finite part

$$ \text{F.P}\sum _{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\exp(-n\epsilon)}{n}= \gamma $$

Euler-Mascheroni constant.

how about the series $ \text{F.P} \sum _{n=1}^{\infty} n^{s}\exp(-n\epsilon)= \zeta (-s) $

Comment: This series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\exp(-n\epsilon)}{n}$ IS convergent to a finite value for any $\epsilon>0$, what do you mean by its finite part?

Answer (score 1):

For the first part:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_0^x t^n \mathrm{d}t \\
&= \int_0^x \sum_{n=0}^\infty t^n \mathrm{d}t \\
&= \int_0^x \frac{1}{1-t} \mathrm{d}t \\
&= \int_0^x \mathrm{d}(-\log(1-t)) \\
&= -\log(1-x)
\end{align}

Plugging in $x = \mathrm{e}^{-\varepsilon}$ yields
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-\varepsilon n}}{n}
&= -\log(1-\mathrm{e}^{-\varepsilon})
\end{align}

As for regularizing the harmonic series, I described one approach [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3204/does-any-method-of-summing-divergent-series-work-on-the-harmonic-series/335176#335176).